# Viber on Debian 9 - No internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, viber

I've got a brand new HP Probook 430. Debian 8.3 stable was not able to meet requirements of new hardware. So I've upgraded to Debian testing (Stretch) and put a new kernel as well - 4.3.
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting + https://scottlinux.com/2013/11/23/how-to-install-newer-kernel-from-debian-wheezy-backports/

I've installed a proper driver for wifi - iwlwifi. I've a connection with a cable as well. Both cases - 50 Mbps nice Internet.

I've downloaded and installed successfully Viber 64 bit. I can start it and type my mobile number. At the next screen I've a notice: "An Internet connection is required to activate your Viber account. Check your connection and try again".

I've a PC with Debian 8.3 running Viber successfully. Both computers are connected to my router. PC - with a cable, laptop - with wifi n.

I've same Viber problem when I connect my laptop with a cable.

Any suggestions?

Best,
Simeon

Comment: It is very difficult to diagnose a problem with so few info. You should use *tcpdump* on your *eth0* connection, and see whether any packet at all leaves your pc, when you try to connect to Viber.  Then show the output.  It is **very** surprising that Viber can work on wifi but not on ethernet.

Comment: To be clear - no Viber connection with both cable and wifi on laptop. PC is another computer, connected to same router with cable and running Viber successfully. So router should not be a problem. I'll paste my console log from tcpdump in a few hours, when having access to the laptop.

Comment: root@debian:/home/omi# tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:46:19.440636 IP debian.49505 > 89.190.192.247.domain: 21472+ A? secure.viber.com. (34)
16:46:19.440681 IP debian.49505 > 89.190.192.247.domain: 20323+ AAAA? secure.viber.com. (34)
16:46:19.441578 IP debian.38986 > 89.190.192.247.domain: 5671+ PTR? 247.192.190.89.in-addr.arpa. (45)
16:46:19.446013 IP 89.190.192.247.domain > debian.38986: 5671 NXDomain 0/1/0 (126)

Comment: 16:46:19.490733 IP 89.190.192.247.domain > debian.49505: 21472 3/4/4 CNAME secure-wa-elb-42596758.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com., A 107.21.15.156, A 52.20.223.63 (328)
16:46:19.490771 IP 89.190.192.247.domain > debian.49505: 20323 1/1/0 CNAME secure-wa-elb-42596758.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. (177)
16:46:19.491454 IP debian.50790 > ec2-107-21-15-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com.https: Flags [S], seq 2129437091, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 471405 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

Comment: 16:46:19.491856 IP debian.53327 > 89.190.192.247.domain: 14042+ PTR? 156.15.21.107.in-addr.arpa. (44)
16:46:19.497337 IP 89.190.192.247.domain > debian.53327: 14042 1/5/6 PTR ec2-107-21-15-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com. (320)
16:46:19.641172 IP ec2-107-21-15-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com.https > debian.50790: Flags [S.], seq 318195133, ack 2129437092, win 14480, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 1668255435 ecr 471405,nop,wscale 8], length 0
16:46:19.641221 IP debian.50790 > ec2-107-21-15-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 471442 ecr 1668255435]...

Comment: 27 packets captured
28 packets received by filter
1 packet dropped by kernel

Comment: @SimeonStavrev Please [edit] the question to include the console logs. They are unreadable when added as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

Download the following certificates

- https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem and
- https://github.com/katmagic/https-everywhere/blob/master/cert-validity/mozilla/builtin-certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.crt

Place them in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Worked for me, and I did need the crt from GitHub (unlike hrv below).

Answer (score 2):

Placing certs in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and running the script didn't work for me on Debian testing x64...

I only needed https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem

Downloaded it and copied/renamed as /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.crt 
(needs to be .crt to be recognised). After that I did 
"sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates"
when asked if I trust new certs I said yes, and then explicitly enabled thawte-Premium_Server_CA which resulted in:

```
    root@hvulin:/etc# dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 175, your new list has 178
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=ZA, S=Western Cape, L=Cape Town, O=Thawte Consulting cc, OU=Certification Services Division, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, E=premium-server@thawte.com
Certificate added: O=CAcert Inc., OU=http://www.CAcert.org, CN=CAcert Class 3 Root
Certificate added: O=Root CA, OU=http://www.cacert.org, CN=CA Cert Signing Authority, E=support@cacert.org
Certificate added: C=ZA, S=Western Cape, L=Cape Town, O=Thawte Consulting cc, OU=Certification Services Division, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, E=premium-server@thawte.com
Certificate added: C=US, O="thawte, Inc.", OU=Certification Services Division, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=thawte Primary Root CA
6 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
Done
done.
```

Comment: This solution works for me. However, when reconfiguring ca-certificates, I decided to select "ask" when asked if it should trust and install new CA certificates. This opened another window, where I ticked the new Thawte certificate.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to install `libssl1.0-dev`. I did `sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev` but this didn't help me.

Installing `libssl1.0-dev` did the trick.

Comment: This is the correct solution for me - Kali Linux on Debian 9

Answer (score 1):

for fedora:

```
sudo dnf install openssl openssl-devel
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 /opt/viber/lib/libssl.so
```

see: https://bytefreaks.net/applications/viber-desktop-on-fedora-27-64bit-viber-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-openssl-error for an explanation

Comment: That's all what was needed on FC30

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help to you:
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev

Comment: More detail would help

Answer (score -1):

btw i had this problem and i downloaded ibssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u7_amd64.deb from link:
 https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0
 and installed and then again installed viber

after downloading ibssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u7_amd64.deb

and get into the file directory you put the downloaded file and type ls 
then type dpkg -i  like this

dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u7_amd64.deb
 then go back to the file directory where the viber.deb file is then type 
ls
then type dpkg -i  like this
dpkg -i viber.deb

then good to go hope you got your error fixed